# How can i use fork to open a new process and use execl to start a web browser in c

Tags: c, fork, os.execl

I would like to create a new process using fork and then use excl to start a web browser with a url.
Im not too familiar with fork and excel so any help would be appreciated.
thanks

EDIT:
this is my code but i don't think its right

```
if(fork() == 0) {
      execl (url,0);
      printf("Route opened in brwoser\n");
    } else {
      printf("Route cannot be opened.\n");
    }
```

Comment: It also should be `fork() == 0`. And what is `url`?

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual pages of these calls first:

```
man 2 fork
man 3 execl
```

The syscall `fork()` makes a copy of the process and returns in both, returning the child process ID in the parent and zero in the child. If it returns a negative number, it means it's failed.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
    printf("Fork failed\n");
else if (pid > 0) /* Here comes the parent process */
    printf("Fork successful\n");
else /* Here comes the child process */
    ...
```

On the other hand `execl()` does not return at all. It throws away your program, and replaces it with image of the one specified in its arguments in the same process.

If `execl()` returns, it's an error. It probably did not find the program you specified.

Its arguments are the called program (an URL is not a program) and its arguments.

```
...
else { /* Here comes the child process */
    execl("/usr/bin/firefox", "/usr/bin/firefox", "example.com", (char*)NULL);
    printf("Could not execute Firefox\n");
}
```